# How can I obtain a unit vector of a shifted spherical system?

Tags: coordinate-systems

I hope that I can explain myself clear enough, 
Assuming i have a sphere that has been moved down in the Z-axis.
I know that the radial unit vector when the sphere is not shifted can be expressed as:
$$\hat{r} = \sin\theta\cos\phi \,\hat{x} + \sin\theta\sin\phi \,\hat{y} + \cos\theta\,\hat{z}$$
where $\hat{x}$, $\hat{y}$, and $\hat{z}$ are the Cartesian unit vectors.
But how can I obtain $\hat{r}$ over the surface of the sphere in a situation when the sphere has been shifted?
like in the picture I added?[image]

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: Consider the transformation that took the system from sphere-at-origin to sphere-not-at-origin (i.e. $z' \leftarrow z-2R$). Now consider the reverse transformation...

Comment: I agree with @KyleKanos However short answer: If you have a parametrisation $r(x1,x2,x3)$ you can always find a local tripod via computing $\partial_{x_i} r$

Comment: The way you've drawn $\hat r$ in the diagram, it hasn't changed due to the shift. If you want something else than what you've already written, it needs to be reflected in the diagram.